# Crowdsourcing a Complete list of Common Java System Properties and Known Values

Tags: java, properties, system-properties, crowdsourcing

*I've been inspired by another question: [Best Practice for Using Java System Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487590/best-practice-for-using-java-system-properties)*

I'm currently looking for a complete list of Java system properties and possible values. I'm working on a simple class to simplify use of them (If you're interested, [get the source](http://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils/raw/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/utils/properties/SystemProperty.java) and [background info (my blog)](http://techblog.molindo.at/2009/11/java-system-properties.html)). With this class, I try to provide the following:

- simple and consistent access to Java system properties (no String constants)
- *full* documentation of available properties and their possible values – within my IDE (i.e. auto-completion, inline Javadoc)
- fix inconsistencies in returned values and/or naming
- make sure that java.io.tmpdir exists – acutally that’s the main reason why I’m doing all this :)

To get full documentation and a complete list of available properties (even those where availability is heavily JVM-dependent), I'd like you to [download the source](http://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils/raw/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/utils/properties/SystemProperty.java), run it and post your results. I'll update the class accordingly and keep it available at the given location. Hopefully, it will ease live of some of you out there :)

Edit:

I'm not looking for standard properties as described by [System.getProperties()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) or all properties that are available on my system. I'm trying to create a comprehensive list of system properties - even those that are vendor, jvm or version related - those that aren't guaranteed to exist and whose documentation is sparse or hard to find. Properties like

- sun.desktop (Linux only, e.g. "gnome"),
- awt.toolkit (Mac only, e.g. apple.awt.CToolkit)
- sun.cpu.endian (Sun JVMs only)
- ...

I'd love to get others to run my code and post their results in order to compile a comprehensive list (with extensive documentation of properties and their possible values) in the form of a Java enum that's easy to use e.g.:

```
String file = SystemProperty.JAVA_IO_TMPDIR + "file.txt";
```

instead of

```
String tmp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
if (!tmp.endsWith(File.separator)
    tmp += File.separator;
new File(tmp).mkdirs(); // make sure tmp exists
String file = tmp + "file.txt";
```

So please run that code and post your findings. Here is a simple script to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
# download and run
# you should really look at the code first, as you can't be sure
# that I'm a trustworthy guy ;)
wget -N http://techblog.molindo.at/files/SystemProperty.java
javac SystemProperty.java
java SystemProperty
```

*(I know this isn't a real question but rather a crowd sourcing thing. I hope nobody minds)*

**Bounty:**

As there is no correct answer to this question, the bounty will be awarded to the person who discovers most new system properties. As a hint: testing non-standard JVMs (J2ME, Android, GCJ, OpenJDK, Apache Harmony, ...) and common languages on top of the JVM (Groovy, Scala, JRuby, ..) should be especially yielding.

Current leaders:

1. [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/crowdsourcing-a-complete-list-of-common-java-system-properties-and-known-values/1859729#1859729) 19 discovered properties
2. [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/complete-list-of-available-java-system-properties-and-known-values/1815698#1815698) 14 discovered properties
3. [Joa Ebert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/crowdsourcing-a-complete-list-of-common-java-system-properties-and-known-values/1867710#1867710) 8 discovered properties
4. [Suraj Chandran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/complete-list-of-available-java-system-properties-and-known-values/1803144#1803144) 1 discovered property

Btw, I'm planning to release the final result as a Maven artifact and upload it to the central repository as soon as I have enough input.

**UPDATE: Public Repository, finally**

[SystemProperty.java](http://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/at/molindo/utils/properties/SystemProperty.java) is now available on GitHub, as part of the [molindo-utils project](http://github.com/molindo/molindo-utils). molindo-utils is currently available as [1.0-SNAPSHOT through Sonatype's OSS repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/at/molindo/molindo-utils/1.0-SNAPSHOT/). As soon as it's ready for release, it will be synchronized to Maven central as well.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>at.molindo</groupId>
    <artifactId>molindo-utils</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You should remove the dependency on slf4j

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for that hint, I've removed it.

Comment: If you stuff the system properties in a hashtree before iterating, you get a sorted output.

Comment: I guess you meant TreeMap rather than hashtree which doesn't exist (or does it?). But that's exactly what I've done.

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396056/what-are-the-java-platform-defaults/1396299#1396299](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396056/what-are-the-java-platform-defaults/1396299#1396299)

Comment: I don't see the point of this.  The idea of trying to enumerate every possible property key as enum constants seems like folly, it's a moving target.

Comment: The point isn't to enumerate every possible key. The most important point is documenting what properties are common and what their known values are. This should help to leverage existing IDE capabilities like auto-completion and inline javadoc to facilitate using them (no need for documentation outside the IDE anymore, no (copy-paste of) string literals). Documentation of common values should help to derive more information, e.g. os.name (Maven fame) or java.vm.server (see http://j.mp/6E4wYM). I'm not yet sure whether an enum really is the best way. Any other ideas?

Comment: A link to yet another link, are you serious? ;) Just kidding, it's indeed very helpful, thanks.

Comment: this way @RealHowTo can get rep on both answers.  I will bite.

Comment: Hey ! that's a good idea =:-) ... but it was only to recycle a previous answer.

Comment: Why does this list not contain `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS AIX 5.3, Java version:

```
java version "1.5.0"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build pap32devifx-20090506 (SR9-SSU +PK76176+IZ44410+IZ44495))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.3, J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223ifx-20090225 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20090224_30451_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20081112_1511ifx1_r8
GC   - 200811_07)
```

SystemProperty output:

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=ISO8859-1 (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=null (read-only)
FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=/ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=49.0 (read-only)
JAVA_COMPILER: java.compiler=j9jit23 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=/prj/was/java/jre (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=/tmp/
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=/prj/was/java/jre/bin:/prj/was/java/jre/bin:/prj/was/java/jre/bin/classic:/prj/was/java/jre/bin:/prj/was/java/jre/bin/j9vm:/usr/lib (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=pap32devifx-20090506 (SR9-SSU +PK76176+IZ44410+IZ44495) (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.5 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.5.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=IBM Corporation (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://www.ibm.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=null (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223ifx-20090225 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20090224_30451_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20081112_1511ifx1_r8
GC   - 200811_07 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=IBM J9 VM (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=2.3 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=IBM Corporation (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=AIX (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=ppc (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=5.3 (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=: (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=32 (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=/prj/was/java/jre/lib/vm.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/core.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/graphics.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/security.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmpkcs.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmorb.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmcfw.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmorbapi.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmjcefw.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmjgssprovider.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmjsseprovider2.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmjaaslm.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/ibmcertpathprovider.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/server.jar:/prj/was/java/jre/lib/xml.jar (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=/prj/was/java/jre/bin (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist=null (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=null (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=ISO8859-1 (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=null (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=null (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=US (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=/tmp/avd (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=/root (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=root (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone= (read-only)
USER_VARIANT: user.variant= (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
USER_ZONEINFO_DIR: user.zoneinfo.dir=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME: gnu.classpath.home=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME_URL: gnu.classpath.home.url=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_VERSION: gnu.classpath.version=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_VM_SHORTNAME: gnu.classpath.vm.shortname=null (read-only)
GNU_CPU_ENDIAN: gnu.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_PRECOMPILED_DB_PATH: gnu.gcj.precompiled.db.path=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_PROGNAME: gnu.gcj.progname=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_RUNTIME_ENDORSED_DIRS: gnu.gcj.runtime.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_USER_REALNAME: gnu.gcj.user.realname=null (read-only)
GNU_JAVA_UTIL_ZONEINFO_DIR: gnu.java.util.zoneinfo.dir=null (read-only)
HTTP_AGENT: http.agent=null (read-only)
JAVA_FULLVERSION: java.fullversion=J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 AIX ppc-32 j9vmap3223ifx-20090225 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20090224_30451_bHdSMr
JIT  - 20081112_1511ifx1_r8
GC   - 200811_07 (read-only)
USER_REGION: user.region=null (read-only)
PROGRAM_NAME: program.name=null (read-only)
GROOVY_HOME: groovy.home=null (read-only)
GROOVY_STARTER_CONF: groovy.starter.conf=null (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_HEADLESS: java.awt.headless=false
SUN_AWT_DISABLE_MIXING: sun.awt.disableMixing=null
SUN_AWT_NOERASEBACKGROUND: sun.awt.noerasebackground=null
SUN_AWT_XEMBEDSERVER: sun.awt.xembedserver=null
OS_FAMILY: os.family=unknown (derived)
JAVA_VM_SERVER: java.vm.server=false (derived)


### UNKNOWN
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=null (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist=null (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=null (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=null (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=null (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
USER_ZONEINFO_DIR: user.zoneinfo.dir=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME: gnu.classpath.home=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME_URL: gnu.classpath.home.url=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_VERSION: gnu.classpath.version=null (read-only)
GNU_CLASSPATH_VM_SHORTNAME: gnu.classpath.vm.shortname=null (read-only)
GNU_CPU_ENDIAN: gnu.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_PRECOMPILED_DB_PATH: gnu.gcj.precompiled.db.path=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_PROGNAME: gnu.gcj.progname=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_RUNTIME_ENDORSED_DIRS: gnu.gcj.runtime.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
GNU_GCJ_USER_REALNAME: gnu.gcj.user.realname=null (read-only)
GNU_JAVA_UTIL_ZONEINFO_DIR: gnu.java.util.zoneinfo.dir=null (read-only)
HTTP_AGENT: http.agent=null (read-only)
USER_REGION: user.region=null (read-only)
PROGRAM_NAME: program.name=null (read-only)
GROOVY_HOME: groovy.home=null (read-only)
GROOVY_STARTER_CONF: groovy.starter.conf=null (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_HEADLESS: java.awt.headless=false
SUN_AWT_DISABLE_MIXING: sun.awt.disableMixing=null
SUN_AWT_NOERASEBACKGROUND: sun.awt.noerasebackground=null
SUN_AWT_XEMBEDSERVER: sun.awt.xembedserver=null
OS_FAMILY: os.family=unknown (derived)
JAVA_VM_SERVER: java.vm.server=false (derived)


### MISSING
com.ibm.cpu.endian=big
com.ibm.oti.configuration=scar
com.ibm.oti.jcl.build=20081111_1646
com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path=/prj/was/java/jre/bin
com.ibm.oti.vm.library.version=23
com.ibm.util.extralibs.properties=
com.ibm.vm.bitmode=32
ibm.signalhandling.rs=false
ibm.signalhandling.sigchain=true
ibm.signalhandling.sigint=true
ibm.system.encoding=ISO8859-1
invokedviajava=
java.assistive=ON
java.awt.fonts=
java.jcl.version=20090506
java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferencesFactory
jxe.current.romimage.version=9
jxe.lowest.romimage.version=9
sun.java2d.fontpath=


### PLEASE POST FULL OUTPUT AT http://j.mp/props0 or http://j.mp/props1
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: big
     */
    COM_IBM_CPU_ENDIAN("com.ibm.cpu.endian"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: scar
     */
    COM_IBM_OTI_CONFIGURATION("com.ibm.oti.configuration"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 20081111_1646
     */
    COM_IBM_OTI_JCL_BUILD("com.ibm.oti.jcl.build"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: /prj/was/java/jre/bin
     */
    COM_IBM_OTI_VM_BOOTSTRAP_LIBRARY_PATH("com.ibm.oti.vm.bootstrap.library.path"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 23
     */
    COM_IBM_OTI_VM_LIBRARY_VERSION("com.ibm.oti.vm.library.version"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 
     */
    COM_IBM_UTIL_EXTRALIBS_PROPERTIES("com.ibm.util.extralibs.properties"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 32
     */
    COM_IBM_VM_BITMODE("com.ibm.vm.bitmode"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: false
     */
    IBM_SIGNALHANDLING_RS("ibm.signalhandling.rs"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: true
     */
    IBM_SIGNALHANDLING_SIGCHAIN("ibm.signalhandling.sigchain"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: true
     */
    IBM_SIGNALHANDLING_SIGINT("ibm.signalhandling.sigint"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: ISO8859-1
     */
    IBM_SYSTEM_ENCODING("ibm.system.encoding"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 
     */
    INVOKEDVIAJAVA("invokedviajava"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: ON
     */
    JAVA_ASSISTIVE("java.assistive"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 
     */
    JAVA_AWT_FONTS("java.awt.fonts"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 20090506
     */
    JAVA_JCL_VERSION("java.jcl.version"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferencesFactory
     */
    JAVA_UTIL_PREFS__PREFERENCES_FACTORY("java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 9
     */
    JXE_CURRENT_ROMIMAGE_VERSION("jxe.current.romimage.version"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 9
     */
    JXE_LOWEST_ROMIMAGE_VERSION("jxe.lowest.romimage.version"),
    /**
     * AIX only: known values: 
     */
    SUN_JAVA2D_FONTPATH("sun.java2d.fontpath"),
```

Answer (score 8):

From the javadoc of [System.getProperties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()), only these are guaranteed:

```
java.version - Java Runtime Environment version 
java.vendor - Java Runtime Environment vendor 
java.vendor.url - Java vendor URL 
java.home Java - installation directory 
java.vm.specification.version - Java Virtual Machine specification version 
java.vm.specification.vendor - Java Virtual Machine specification vendor 
java.vm.specification.name - Java Virtual Machine specification name 
java.vm.version - Java Virtual Machine implementation version 
java.vm.vendor - Java Virtual Machine implementation vendor 
java.vm.name - Java Virtual Machine implementation name 
java.specification.version - Java Runtime Environment specification version 
java.specification.vendor - Java Runtime Environment specification vendor 
java.specification.name - Java Runtime Environment specification name 
java.class.version - Java class format version number 
java.class.path - Java class path 
java.library.path - List of paths to search when loading libraries 
java.io.tmpdir - Default temp file path 
java.compiler - Name of JIT compiler to use 
java.ext.dirs - Path of extension directory or directories 
os.name - Operating system name 
os.arch - Operating system architecture 
os.version - Operating system version 
file.separator - File separator ("/" on UNIX) 
path.separator - Path separator (":" on UNIX) 
line.separator - Line separator ("\n" on UNIX) 
user.name - User's account name 
user.home - User's home directory 
user.dir - User's current working directory
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, thanks for your reply. I know about this list, but it's a) not complete (I'm also interested in properties that are only available on some Systems) and b) doesn't give any hints about possible values (e.g. for os.name). That's why I try to gather this information and make it accessible in another (better?) way.

Comment: then i guess the only way to run your system in every single environement and do System.getProperties().list(System.out)

Comment: Which is exactly what I'm trying to do :) But instead of `System.getProperties().list(System.out)` please use the code that I've provided (it generates Java code and some Javadoc for those properties that are currently missing) and paste your results. Please help! :)

Comment: k....Here you go.....

### UNKNOWN
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### MISSING
user.variant=

Comment: user.variant? what's your environment? OS, JVM?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the output from a 64-bit Linux (Fedora 11), Sun Java:

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=UTF-8 (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=sun.io (read-only)
FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=/ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=50.0 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=/tmp/
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=OpenJDK Runtime Environment (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=1.6.0_0-b16 (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.6 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.6.0_0 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=mixed mode (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=14.0-b16 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=Linux (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=amd64 (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=2.6.30.9-96.fc11.x86_64 (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=: (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=64 (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/classes (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64 (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=little (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist= (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Server Compiler (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=unknown (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=US (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=/disk/a/3/home/bc (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=/home/bc (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=bc (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone= (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=gnome (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### UNKNOWN
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### MISSING
user.zoneinfo.dir=/usr/share/javazi


### PLEASE POST THIS AT http://j.mp/props0 or http://j.mp/props1
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: /usr/share/javazi
     */
    USER_ZONEINFO_DIR("user.zoneinfo.dir"),
```

And, just for fun, the output from the same system using the gcj java runtime:

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=UTF-8 (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=null (read-only)

FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=/ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=null (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=null (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=49.0 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=/usr/share/java/ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=/tmp/
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=/usr/lib64/gcj-4.4.1 (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=null (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=1.5.0 (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java(tm) Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.5 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.5.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=Free Software Foundation, Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://gcc.gnu.org/java/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=null (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=GNU libgcj 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2) (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=GNU libgcj (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java(tm) Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2) (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=Free Software Foundation, Inc. (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=Linux (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=x86_64 (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=2.6.30.9-96.fc11.x86_64 (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=: (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=null (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre/lib/rt.jar (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist=null (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=null (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=null (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=null (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=null (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=null (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=null (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=/disk/a/3/home/bc (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=/home/bc (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=bc (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone=null (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### UNKNOWN
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=null (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=null (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=null (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=null (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=null (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=null (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=null (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=null (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist=null (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=null (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=null (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=null (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=null (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=null (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=null (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone=null (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### MISSING
gnu.classpath.home=/usr
gnu.classpath.home.url=file:///usr/lib64
gnu.classpath.version=0.98
gnu.classpath.vm.shortname=libgcj
gnu.cpu.endian=little
gnu.gcj.precompiled.db.path=/usr/lib64/gcj-4.4.1/classmap.db
gnu.gcj.progname=SystemProperty
gnu.gcj.runtime.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/java/gcj-endorsed
gnu.gcj.user.realname=
gnu.java.util.zoneinfo.dir=/usr/share/zoneinfo
http.agent=gnu-classpath/0.98 (libgcj/4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2))
java.fullversion=GNU libgcj 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)
user.region=US


### PLEASE POST THIS AT http://j.mp/props0 or http://j.mp/props1
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: /usr
     */
    GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME("gnu.classpath.home"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: file:///usr/lib64
     */
    GNU_CLASSPATH_HOME_URL("gnu.classpath.home.url"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: 0.98
     */
    GNU_CLASSPATH_VERSION("gnu.classpath.version"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: libgcj
     */
    GNU_CLASSPATH_VM_SHORTNAME("gnu.classpath.vm.shortname"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: little
     */
    GNU_CPU_ENDIAN("gnu.cpu.endian"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: /usr/lib64/gcj-4.4.1/classmap.db
     */
    GNU_GCJ_PRECOMPILED_DB_PATH("gnu.gcj.precompiled.db.path"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: SystemProperty
     */
    GNU_GCJ_PROGNAME("gnu.gcj.progname"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: /usr/share/java/gcj-endorsed
     */
    GNU_GCJ_RUNTIME_ENDORSED_DIRS("gnu.gcj.runtime.endorsed.dirs"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: 
     */
    GNU_GCJ_USER_REALNAME("gnu.gcj.user.realname"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: /usr/share/zoneinfo
     */
    GNU_JAVA_UTIL_ZONEINFO_DIR("gnu.java.util.zoneinfo.dir"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: gnu-classpath/0.98 (libgcj/4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2))
     */
    HTTP_AGENT("http.agent"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: GNU libgcj 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)
     */
    JAVA_FULLVERSION("java.fullversion"),
    /**
     * Linux only: known values: US
     */
    USER_REGION("user.region"),
```

Comment: Thanks - especially for the gcj output!

Answer (score 2):

Windows workstation:

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=Cp1252 (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=sun.io (read-only)
FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=\ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=50.0 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\endorsed (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=C:\DOCUME~1\alex\LOCALS~1\Temp\
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\cygwin\usr\X11R6\bin;C:\cygwin\home\alex\bin;c:\windows\system32;c:\vslick\win;c:\ruby\bin;c:\cvs (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=1.6.0_14-b08 (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.6 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.6.0_14 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=14.0-b16 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=Windows XP (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=x86 (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=5.1 (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=; (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=32 (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\resources.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\jsse.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\jce.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\charsets.jar;c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\classes (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=c:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\bin (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=little (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist=pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86 (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252 (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 3 (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=US (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=C:\cygwin\home\alex (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=C:\Documents and Settings\alex (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=alex (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone= (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=windows (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### UNKNOWN
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### MISSING
user.variant=


### PLEASE POST THIS AT ${url.goes.here}
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: 
     */
    USER_VARIANT("user.variant"),
```

CentOS workstation:

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=UTF-8 (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=sun.io (read-only)
FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=/ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=50.0 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/endorsed (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=/tmp/
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=1.6.0_11-b03 (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.6 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.6.0_11 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://java.sun.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=http://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=mixed mode (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=11.0-b16 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=Linux (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=amd64 (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=2.6.18-164.6.1.el5xen (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=: (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=64 (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/classes (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_11/jre/lib/amd64 (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=little (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist= (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8 (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Server Compiler (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=unknown (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=US (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=/tmp (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=/root (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=root (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone= (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)


### UNKNOWN
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=null (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=null (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=null (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=null (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=null (read-only)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a question regarding sun.desktop: Did you run the code from within an X session?

Comment: No, ssh console session.  The machine is running in non-graphical mode ( init level 3 ).

Comment: Thanks! I'll add this to the doc. Would be interesting to know whether this property is available from an X session on this machine ... ;)

Comment: @sfussenegger.  Sorry, can't help you here.  All of our Linux servers run in mode 3. Real men don't run GUI :)

Comment: *real* men run a a GUI they compiled from source! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Nice idea, here's my output

Mac OS X v10.6.2 (Snow Leopard)

```
FILE_ENCODING: file.encoding=MacRoman (read-only)
FILE_ENCODING_PKG: file.encoding.pkg=sun.io (read-only)
FILE_SEPARATOR: file.separator=/ (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_GRAPHICSENV: java.awt.graphicsenv=apple.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment (read-only)
JAVA_AWT_PRINTERJOB: java.awt.printerjob=apple.awt.CPrinterJob (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_PATH: java.class.path=. (read-only)
JAVA_CLASS_VERSION: java.class.version=50.0 (read-only)
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS: java.endorsed.dirs=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/endorsed (read-only)
JAVA_EXT_DIRS: java.ext.dirs=/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/ext (read-only)
JAVA_HOME: java.home=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home (read-only)
JAVA_IO_TMPDIR: java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/Fe/Feu91UDiHiCITh22R9y2VE+++TI/-Tmp-/
JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH: java.library.path=.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_NAME: java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (read-only)
JAVA_RUNTIME_VERSION: java.runtime.version=1.6.0_15-b03-219 (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.specification.version=1.6 (read-only)
JAVA_VERSION: java.version=1.6.0_15 (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR: java.vendor=Apple Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL: java.vendor.url=http://www.apple.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VENDOR_URL_BUG: java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.apple.com/ (read-only)
JAVA_VM_INFO: java.vm.info=mixed mode (read-only)
JAVA_VM_NAME: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_NAME: java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VENDOR: java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc. (read-only)
JAVA_VM_SPECIFICATION_VERSION: java.vm.specification.version=1.0 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VERSION: java.vm.version=14.1-b02-90 (read-only)
JAVA_VM_VENDOR: java.vm.vendor=Apple Inc. (read-only)
LINE_SEPARATOR: line.separator=
 (read-only)
OS_NAME: os.name=Mac OS X (read-only)
OS_ARCH: os.arch=x86_64 (read-only)
OS_VERSION: os.version=10.6.2 (read-only)
PATH_SEPARATOR: path.separator=: (read-only)
SUN_ARCH_DATA_MODEL: sun.arch.data.model=64 (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_CLASS_PATH: sun.boot.class.path=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jsfd.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Frameworks/JavaRuntimeSupport.framework/Resources/Java/JavaRuntimeSupport.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/ui.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/laf.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/sunrsasign.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jsse.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/jce.jar:/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/charsets.jar (read-only)
SUN_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH: sun.boot.library.path=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Libraries (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ENDIAN: sun.cpu.endian=little (read-only)
SUN_CPU_ISALIST: sun.cpu.isalist= (read-only)
SUN_IO_UNICODE_ENCODING: sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle (read-only)
SUN_JAVA_LAUNCHER: sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD (read-only)
SUN_JNU_ENCODING: sun.jnu.encoding=MacRoman (read-only)
SUN_MANAGEMENT_COMPILER: sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Server Compiler (read-only)
SUN_OS_PATCH_LEVEL: sun.os.patch.level=unknown (read-only)
USER_COUNTRY: user.country=US (read-only)
USER_DIR: user.dir=/Users/msp/Documents (read-only)
USER_HOME: user.home=/Users/msp (read-only)
USER_LANGUAGE: user.language=en (read-only)
USER_NAME: user.name=msp (read-only)
USER_TIMEZONE: user.timezone= (read-only)
SUN_DESKTOP: sun.desktop=null (read-only)
AWT_NATIVE_DOUBLE_BUFFERING: awt.nativeDoubleBuffering=true (read-only)
AWT_TOOLKIT: awt.toolkit=apple.awt.CToolkit (read-only)
FTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 (read-only)
GOPHER_PROXY_SET: gopherProxySet=false (read-only)
HTTP_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 (read-only)
MRJ_VERSION: mrj.version=1060.1.6.0_15-219 (read-only)
SOCKS_NON_PROXY_HOSTS: socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 (read-only)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#IBM 1.4 win32
#Thu Nov 26 15:21:36 GMT 2009
java.assistive=ON
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition
sun.boot.library.path=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\bin
java.vm.version=1.4.2
java.vm.vendor=IBM Corporation
java.vendor.url=http\://www.ibm.com/
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Classic VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.country=GB
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 3
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C\:\\somepath\\Props
java.runtime.version=1.4.2
java.fullversion=J2RE 1.4.2 IBM Windows 32 build cn142-20040926 (JIT enabled\: jitc)
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\endorsed
os.arch=x86
com.ibm.vm.bitmode=32
java.io.tmpdir=C\:\\DOCUME~1\\AUser\\LOCALS~1\\Temp\\
line.separator=\r\n
java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
user.variant=
java.awt.fonts=
os.name=Windows XP
sun.java2d.fontpath=
java.library.path=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\bin;.;C\:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C\:\\WINDOWS;C\:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C\:\\WINDOWS;C\:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=48.0
ibm.system.encoding=Cp1252
invokedviajava=
java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferencesFactory
os.version=5.1
user.home=C\:\\Documents and Settings\\AUser
user.timezone=Europe/London
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding=Cp1252
java.specification.version=1.4
java.class.path=C\:\\path\\Props\\bin
user.name=AUser
java.vm.specification.version=1.0
java.home=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2
sun.arch.data.model=32
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=J2RE 1.4.2 IBM Windows 32 build cn142-20040926 (JIT enabled\: jitc)
java.version=1.4.2
java.ext.dirs=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ext
sun.boot.class.path=Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\core.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\graphics.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\security.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\server.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\xml.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\charsets.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmcertpathprovider.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjaasactivelm.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjaaslm.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjcefw.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjgssprovider.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjssefips.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmjsseprovider.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmorb.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmorbapi.jar;Z\:\\path\\jre-j91.4.2\\lib\\ibmpkcs.jar
java.vendor=IBM Corporation
file.separator=\\
java.vendor.url.bug=
java.compiler=jitc
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
```

Comment: great ... the first non-Sun JVM :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

List all your by:

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
```

Comment: Well ... how's that supposed to be helpful? The output would be much more interesting than the code.

Answer (score 1):

JRockit

- java version "1.6.0_05"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_05-b13)
- BEA JRockit(R) (build R27.6.0-50_o-100423-1.6.0_05-20080626-2105-windows-ia32, compiled   mode)

```
### MISSING
java.vm.vendor.url=http://www.bea.com/
java.vm.vendor.url.bug=http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/go2troubleshooting.html


### PLEASE POST FULL OUTPUT AT http://j.mp/props0 or http://j.mp/props1
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: http://www.bea.com/
     */
    JAVA_VM_VENDOR_URL("java.vm.vendor.url"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: http://edocs.bea.com/jrockit/go2troubleshooting.html
     */
    JAVA_VM_VENDOR_URL_BUG("java.vm.vendor.url.bug"),
```

Apache Harmony

- Apache Harmony Launcher : (c) Copyright 1991, 2009 The Apache Software Foundation or its licensors, as applicable.
- java version "1.5.0"
- Apache Harmony (1.5.0)
- DRLVM (11.2.0)
- pre-alpha : not complete or compatible
- svn = r885602, (Dec  1 2009), Windows/ia32/msvc 1500, release build
- http://harmony.apache.org

```
### MISSING
java.tmpdir=C:\...\Temp
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
org.apache.harmony.boot.class.path=C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\accessibility.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\annotation.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\applet.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\archive.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\auth.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\awt.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\beans.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\concurrent.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\crypto.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\imageio.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\instrument.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\jndi.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\lang-management.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\logging.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\luni.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\math.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio_char.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\prefs.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\print.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\regex.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\rmi.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\security.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sound.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sql.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\swing.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\text.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x_mgt.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x-net.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xml.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1/icu4j-4_2_1.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1/icu4j-charsets-4_2_1.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xalan-j_2.7.0/xalan.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/resolver.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/xercesImpl.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/xml-apis.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2/mx4j.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2/mx4j-remote.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\misc.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-core.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-rmi-spec.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-rmi-impl.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\bcel-5.2/bcel-5.2.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\pack200.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\asm-3.1/asm-3.1.jar
org.apache.harmony.vm.vmdir=c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default
vm.boot.class.path=c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\gc_gen.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\kernel.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\vmmagic-20070207.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\antlr-2.7.5.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\accessibility.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\annotation.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\applet.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\archive.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\auth.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\awt.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\beans.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\concurrent.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\crypto.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\imageio.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\instrument.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\jndi.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\lang-management.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\logging.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\luni.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\math.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio_char.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\prefs.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\print.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\regex.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\rmi.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\security.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sound.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sql.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\swing.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\text.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x-net.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1\icu4j-4_2_1.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1\icu4j-charsets-4_2_1.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xalan-j_2.7.0\xalan.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\resolver.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\xercesimpl.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\xml-apis.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2\mx4j.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2\mx4j-remote.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\misc.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-core.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-rmi-spec.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-rmi-impl.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\bcel-5.2\bcel-5.2.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\pack200.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\asm-3.1\asm-3.1.jar
vm.boot.library.path=c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin


### PLEASE POST FULL OUTPUT AT http://j.mp/props0 or http://j.mp/props1
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: C:\..\Temp
     */
    JAVA_TMPDIR("java.tmpdir"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
     */
    JAVAX_XML_TRANSFORM__TRANSFORMER_FACTORY("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\accessibility.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\annotation.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\applet.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\archive.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\auth.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\awt.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\beans.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\concurrent.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\crypto.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\imageio.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\instrument.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\jndi.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\lang-management.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\logging.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\luni.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\math.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio_char.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\prefs.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\print.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\regex.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\rmi.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\security.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sound.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sql.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\swing.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\text.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x_mgt.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x-net.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xml.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1/icu4j-4_2_1.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1/icu4j-charsets-4_2_1.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xalan-j_2.7.0/xalan.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/resolver.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/xercesImpl.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1/xml-apis.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2/mx4j.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2/mx4j-remote.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\misc.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-core.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-rmi-spec.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0/yoko-rmi-impl.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\bcel-5.2/bcel-5.2.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\pack200.jar;C:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\asm-3.1/asm-3.1.jar
     */
    ORG_APACHE_HARMONY_BOOT_CLASS_PATH("org.apache.harmony.boot.class.path"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default
     */
    ORG_APACHE_HARMONY_VM_VMDIR("org.apache.harmony.vm.vmdir"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\gc_gen.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\kernel.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\vmmagic-20070207.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default\antlr-2.7.5.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\accessibility.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\annotation.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\applet.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\archive.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\auth.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\awt.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\beans.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\concurrent.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\crypto.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\imageio.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\instrument.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\jndi.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\lang-management.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\logging.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\luni.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\math.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\nio_char.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\prefs.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\print.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\regex.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\rmi.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\security.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sound.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\sql.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\swing.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\text.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\x-net.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1\icu4j-4_2_1.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\icu4j_4.2.1\icu4j-charsets-4_2_1.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xalan-j_2.7.0\xalan.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\resolver.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\xercesimpl.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\xerces_2.9.1\xml-apis.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2\mx4j.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\mx4j_3.0.2\mx4j-remote.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\misc.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-core.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-rmi-spec.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\yoko-1.0\yoko-rmi-impl.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\bcel-5.2\bcel-5.2.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\pack200.jar;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\lib\boot\asm-3.1\asm-3.1.jar
     */
    VM_BOOT_CLASS_PATH("vm.boot.class.path"),
    /**
     * Windows XP only: known values: c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin\default;c:\harmony-5.0-jre-885602\bin
     */
    VM_BOOT_LIBRARY_PATH("vm.boot.library.path"),
```

Answer (score 0):

you missing one very important Property today:  "sun.awt.exception.handler"
it helps to catch exceptions on the evt-thread..