# How do I tell if the JVM is honoring the "-server" argument?

Tags: java, jvm, behavior

I am attempting to reproduce some behavior in one of our production environments.  Although it is a bit of a longshot, I know that in our production environment the system is using the "-server" version of the JVM (as they are server boxes).  I would like to validate that there is nothing weird going on there, and want to make sure my test environment is using the same flag.  How can I verify that the local JVM is taking the flag - i.e. is not starting up in "-client" anyway?  Is there a system property I can check?  Or some behavior to look for?

Comment: What does `java -server -version` say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make sure I'm using the "server" JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833129/how-to-make-sure-im-using-the-server-jvm)

Comment: @Pointy: "java version "1.6.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_04-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 10.0-b19, mixed mode)"

Comment: @dogbane I searched and searched for one, because I was certain that this had been asked before *sigh*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read the `java.vm.name` System property and it should contain something like `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));
```

Comment: That showed me exactly what I was looking for - the key was the "server" vs "client" in the vm name - Thanks!