# os.name system property value in Java for Windows Server 2008

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, system-properties

Does anyone know the value of the Java system property "os.name" on Windows Server 2008?  I found a rally going here ([Crowdsourcing a Complete list of Common Java System Properties and Known Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/crowdsourcing-a-complete-list-of-common-java-system-properties-and-known-values)), but nothing on Windows Server 2008.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is "Windows Server 2008" and "Windows Server 2008 R2"