# Are Java system properties always non-null?

Tags: java, java-home, system-properties, home-directory

There are a couple of [Java system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), among them things like `java.home` and `path.separator`, `user.home`. The [spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) does not mention any formal promises on the existence of those values.

Especially I am interested in `user.home`. Does it always point to some existing path?

Comment: i think these are keys

Comment: @anshulkatta; I guess the keys always exist - but the question is, do they always point to something (sane?).

Comment: @miku keys only exist when there is a value, check my answer below

Comment: `user.home` is os dependent but it rarely gets it wrong

Comment: @fge, yes that is my impression, too. I'm just curious under which circumstances a default value might not be set. My *use case*: app creates a `~/.mycache` file on startup; do I need to explicitly check for the existence of `user.home` beforehand?

Comment: Well, you don't have to, you can just `Files.createDirectories()`; if it fails you know the JVM lies to you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can safely assume that all the properties *in that list* is always available in any recent (Oracle-provided) JVM.

However, a `null` check is more defensive, and not expensive in this case.

I've never seen `user.home` to be null or be incorrectly specified by default. However, keep in mind that users can override with `-Duser.home=...`, so you can't rely on it to point to an existing path.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that user can set any property to something nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation you pointed out states

`The getProperty method returns a string containing the value of the property. If the property does not exist, this version of getProperty returns null.`

So if the property does not exist you get a `null` value

Comment: I'm not sure that is what he meant. Surely the Java system property "mambo.jumbo" will be null no problem, but is it possible for a regular property to be uninitialized?

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki: Yes, I am more interested in the conditions when the "default" properties are not defined (not considering the case, when the user set them explicitly to garbage, like `application.jar -Duser.home=good/luck`.

Answer (score 1):

The spec says that `user.home` contains user home directory, it does not say it may contain `null`. I have no doubt that JVM guarantees that it is always set.

Answer (score 1):

The default properties will differ depending on OS. There will be some keys for which no values are defined. On my machine I found `user.variant` and `user.timezone` without any values! Following is the code which will list down all the key value pairs:

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();     
      Set<Object> set = prop.keySet();    
      Iterator<Object> itr = set.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext()){

          Object obj = itr.next();
          String propVal = System.getProperty(obj.toString());  
              System.out.println(obj.toString()+" = "+propVal);

      }
    }
```

Regarding your specific reference about `user.home`, it seems it defined most of the time. Check out this [interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/crowdsourcing-a-complete-list-of-common-java-system-properties-and-known-values) where people have posted the list of system properties on different machines.

Comment: The link to the question gave me an answer: [System.getProperties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29): *This set of system properties* **always includes values** *for the following keys*: ... `user.home` ...