# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\...\xxx.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, dll, java-8, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I want to load DLL library to work with it but I have a little problem with this message

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\xx\xx.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform

and this is the code that i used to load my DLL library

```
String arch = System.getProperty(ARCH_OS_CONSTANT);
                if (arch.equals("32")) {
                    System.load("C:\\..\\xx.dll");
                } else if (arch.equals("64")) {
                    System.load("C:\\xx\\xx.dll");
                }
```

and still have the same problem and I hope that I've found a solution thanks

Comment: What's the point of that `if`/`else` when you're using the same exact path in both cases?

Comment: just a fasle code copy, the else if condition for the 64 bit os version

Comment: Then you should edit your question and put the actual code you're running in it.

Comment: done for the update...

Comment: The error message says `C:\VIMS\dll\x86\UFScanner.dll`, so apparently you're not trying to load the correct DLL. What is the value of `arch`?

Comment: the value is 64, and when he want to load the UFScanner.DLL, i get the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the value of `ARCH_OS_CONSTANT` is `"os.arch"` - the standard property name.

If so, your code is assuming that the value of `"os.arch"` for Intel/AMD 32 bit will be `"32"`.  That's not correct.  According to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803075/crowdsourcing-a-complete-list-of-common-java-system-properties-and-known-values), the value will actually be `"x86"`, and for Intel / AMD 64 bit it will be either be `"amd-64"` or `"x86-64"`.

There is also a property called `"sun.arch.data.model"` that can have value `"32"` or `"64"`.  Unfortunately it is not one of the standard properties listed in the javadoc, and some JVMs don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have the wrong Java-Runtime. Maybe you try to load it with the 32-Bit Java-Runtime and it needs to be 64-Bit or the other way around.